# Blazor with signalR: Attempting to reconnect to the server: x of 8

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-7.0, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I've tried to do some blazor stuff with signalR. Based on this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-7.0&preserve-view=true&tabs=visual-studio) tutorial I wanted to do chat app. Step by step from the tutorial. but at the end I can start app in browser on localhost, page is loaded but after a second I have message Attempting to reconnect to the server: 1 of 8.

In devtools console I have:

```
[2023-12-04T09:43:37.205Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'http://localhost:5183/_blazor'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2023-12-04T09:43:37.220Z] Information: WebSocket connected to ws://localhost:5183/_blazor?id=OC5NGtmY6PBlVjFgd2XvFQ.
blazor.server.js:1 [2023-12-04T09:43:37.281Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error.'.
log @ blazor.server.js:1
_stopConnection @ blazor.server.js:1
transport.onclose @ blazor.server.js:1
_close @ blazor.server.js:1
stop @ blazor.server.js:1
_stopInternal @ blazor.server.js:1
await in _stopInternal (async)
stop @ blazor.server.js:1
_processIncomingData @ blazor.server.js:1
Ft.connection.onreceive @ blazor.server.js:1
i.onmessage @ blazor.server.js:1
blazor.server.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error.
at Ft._processIncomingData (blazor.server.js:1:73086)
at Ft.connection.onreceive (blazor.server.js:1:67009)
at i.onmessage (blazor.server.js:1:51322)
_processIncomingData @ blazor.server.js:1
Ft.connection.onreceive @ blazor.server.js:1
i.onmessage @ blazor.server.js:1
await in i.onmessage (async)
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
blazor.server.js:1 [2023-12-04T09:43:40.285Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'http://localhost:5183/_blazor'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2023-12-04T09:43:40.293Z] Information: WebSocket connected to ws://localhost:5183/_blazor?id=Q31qm6zXFYr5JbBC_hAUSQ.
blazor.server.js:1 [2023-12-04T09:43:40.295Z] Error: Error: Circuit host not initialized.
log @ blazor.server.js:1
attemptPeriodicReconnection @ blazor.server.js:1
await in attemptPeriodicReconnection (async)
Yn @ blazor.server.js:1
onConnectionDown @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
_completeClose @ blazor.server.js:1
_connectionClosed @ blazor.server.js:1
Ft.connection.onclose @ blazor.server.js:1
_stopConnection @ blazor.server.js:1
transport.onclose @ blazor.server.js:1
_close @ blazor.server.js:1
stop @ blazor.server.js:1
_stopInternal @ blazor.server.js:1
await in _stopInternal (async)
stop @ blazor.server.js:1
_processIncomingData @ blazor.server.js:1
Ft.connection.onreceive @ blazor.server.js:1
i.onmessage @ blazor.server.js:1
blazor.server.js:1 [2023-12-04T09:44:01.039Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'http://localhost:5183/_blazor'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2023-12-04T09:44:01.046Z] Information: WebSocket connected to ws://localhost:5183/_blazor?id=Kno305ikrIy_wQvu9FFrvw.
blazor.server.js:1 [2023-12-04T09:44:01.048Z] Error: Error: Circuit host not initialized.
```

That behavior is on one of my computers which is in company domain - managed by GP.
Same codes on private laptop works fine. Is there any chance that signalR is blocked by some firewall inbound rules, anything? What should be configured to work with signalR?

Comment: Hi mrmarco, please let your colleagues try it, if the issue still happens, we can confirmed the issue related to the environment in your company.

Comment: You should check the vpn is used or not? If you are not using the vpn, you should ask help from the IT department.

Comment: Yes I'm using VPN on that machine. Maybe VPN is the cause... But do you know what setting should be changed? I can not disable it.

Comment: Hi mrmarco, This problem should not be solved at the code level, you can consult the network administrator first.